# request sent me empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi every one please can someone help me to update user that receive image and updated it then render the user with the image to frontend.i get stuck I search by google but I didn't find what I search for,there's my code :

```
this is the userModel:
import mongoose from "mongoose";



const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    fname: {type: String, required: true},
    phone: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: false},
    image: {type: {name: String, img: {contentType: String, data: Buffer}}, required: false},
    isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false, required: true},
    }, {
        timeStamps: true
    });
    const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
    export defau
```

```
userRouter.post("/upload/:id", async(req, res)=> {
    upload.single("productImage")
    
     const updatedUser = User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$set: {image: {name: req.files.productImage.name, img: {contentType: req.files.productImage.mimetype, data: fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/public/images'))}}}   
       })
    
  res.send("ok");
  console.log(updatedUser)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add option `{new: true}`, so that the document returned has the last updated data, and also send the http response in the callback of the update operation

```
userRouter.post('/upload/:id', async (req, res) => {
  upload.single('productImage');

  const updatedUser = User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      $set: {
        image: {
          name: req.files.productImage.name,
          img: {
            contentType: req.files.productImage.mimetype,
            data: fs.createReadStream(
              path.join(__dirname, '../../../frontend/public/images')
            ),
          },
        },
      },
    },
    { new: true },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (err) return res.send(err);

      res.send(doc);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: your work is good but it send me this error: "no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ADMIN\private\pivate\backend\frontend\public\images'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at"

Comment: Well that means it cant find the file in the path you provided, I can't help you with that, I don't know your folder structure

Comment: when i try to send the updatedUser

Comment: the application is devided in two chunk backend and frontend userRouter is in backend so I try to send image to "frontend/public/images/"

Comment: ok, try with this `path.join(__dirname, '../../../frontend/public/images')`

Comment: const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "../../frontend/public/images")
    },
        
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.name + uuidv1())
    }
});
const upload = multer({storage: storage});